# En paginacion mysql como obtener total de registros cuando se aplica el limit?

Tags: mysql

Actualmente hago dos consultas en mis paginaciones, en una extraigo la lista de datos según la pagina:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 20,10
```

En otra aplico el `COUNT` para obtener cuantos registros en total tiene esa consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla
```

Existe alguna manera de no hacer dos consultas y obtener el numero de registros totales en la misma tabla del `LIMIT` sin importar que se repita?
O algún método para optimizar esa consulta? trabajo con `PHP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` asi:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tabla LIMIT 20,10
```

Y luego para obtener el valor que quieres debes correr este query:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```